# Organización de los contenedores

Tags: html, css, web

Necesito ubicar unos contenedores en un posición especifica pero los están afectando un texto que tengo agregado a esa sección y no he podido arreglar de ninguna manera la ubicación tanto del texto como de los contenedores. Adjunto el código CSS y HTML para alguna ayuda.

```css
.destacados {
    padding: 20px; 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-top: 75px;
 
}
 
.destacados-icon {
    margin-right: 7px;
    margin-top: -3.3%; 
}
 
.destacados-icon img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
 
.destacados-text{
    font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    text-shadow: 0 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
 
.destacados-text::before {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
 
.articulo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 0 0 calc(12% - 5px);
    margin: 0 15px 30px;
    background-color: #142631;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 
.articulo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
 
.articulo:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
 
.articulo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #142631;
}
 
.detalles {
    padding: 5px;
}
 
.detalles h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<section class="destacados">

    <div class="destacados-icon">
        <img src="img/star.png" alt="Icono destacado">
    </div>
    <h2 class="destacados-text">Destacados</h2>

    <div class="articulo">
        <a href="articulos/articulo1.html">
            <img src="img/articulos/img-art1.jpg" alt="Articulo 1">
            <div class="detalles">
                <h2>Artículo 1</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="articulo">
        <a href="articulos/articulo2.html">
            <img src="img/articulos/img-art2.jpg" alt="Articulo 2">
            <div class="detalles">
                <h2>Articulo 2</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="articulo">
        <a href="articulos/articulo3.html">
            <img src="img/articulos/img-art3.jpg" alt="Articulo 3">
            <div class="detalles">
                <h2>Articulo 3"</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
 
</section>
```

Aparte de los contenedores he necesitado ubicar correctamente el texto "Destacados" junto con su icono, pero al tratar de hacerlo me daña el estilo de los contenedores o crea espacios que no quiero.

He probado distintas opciones para la ubicación (principalmente ubicarlos con márgenes) y no han funcionado, en un caso funcionó pero solo organizó los contenedores de los artículos en cuanto al texto "Destacados" se encontrada mal ubicado entonces no me funcionaba esa opción de igual forma.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Todo tu codigo debe estar aca, los links externos se pierden...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Y el resultado esperado como sería?

Comment: El resultado esperado sería la buena ubicación de los contenedores que estén centrados y que la fila para ellos sea de un máximo de 6 artículos, luego en cuanto al texto de destacados que esté alineado a la izquierda con su icono anclado a el (al estilo de una viñeta).